Selling small scenes?
I absolutely love writing small scenes. Smaller than a complete chapter. Is there any website where I can sell them? I am all for selling copyright over to whoever wants to write a story off of them, I am just not sure if it's a thing. I love my own work, I have confirmation from other published authors that it is really good as well. I struggle with writing a whole book, so I was hoping that I could help others by writing scenes to play off of.

Your small scenes might be considered flash-fiction, if they read as complete and stand alone stories. There are many sites buying flash fiction — usually 500-1000 words. The standard professional rate is ~10 cents/word. The sites will usually be genre specific.
As a general rule, the shorter a story, the harder it is to write. If you are crafting scenes that don’t work as stand alone stories, its not likely anyone will be interested in purchasing them.  If you think there is a market for this then you could starting buying and publishing scenes yourself.
It’s great that you’ve gotten good at writing these scenes, the next step might be start studying topics like storytelling and structure. Those are key skills to master to successfully write novels and even short stories.

I bought a book once called "The 3 A.M. Epiphany: Uncommon Writing Exercises that Transform Your Fiction". It contained a bunch of fun writing prompts.
You could do something similar with your scenes. One scene per chapter, each chapter introduces the scene and provides a series of writing prompts for practice.

There really isn't much of a market for plotless scenes because there is not much of an audience for it. People want to read stories where things happen. This is different in images, where viewers are happy with the representation of a state, but in narrative fiction, we want to accompany characters as they attempt to achieve their goals, experience interesting situations, and are surprised by unforeseen turns of events.
If you struggle with writing a whole book, allow yourself to take the time to learn it. A good approach is to begin with shorter works and slowly, as your skill grows, attempt longer and more complex narratives. Many famous authors have begun with short stories and later switched to novels. It is a common career path for writers and has the advantage that there is a market for short stories.
